# how to kill processes under certain directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple python sessions under certain directory like,

```
    lsof test11/
    COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME                          
    python   5838 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11                        
    python   5840 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11                        
    python   5843 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11                        
    python   5845 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11                        
    python   5846 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11                        
    python   5847 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11                        
    bash    68363 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11                        
    python  68510 user1  cwd    DIR   8,34     4096 19947539 test11
```

Can can I kill above all python sessions (except bash) in a simple batch script? Thanks.

Comment: `pkill python` should probably do it.

Comment: @l'L'l, that will cause some other program using python will be killed too right

Comment: have a look https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50573/191874

Comment: @Kumar, yes, that would kill any instance of Python.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50573/191874. Below will do the needful.

```
for pid in $(lsof test11/ | grep "python" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done
```

Comment: As is, your command will also kill opened **files** with `python` in their name. To prevent this change `"python"` with `"^python"`. I suggest: `kill -9 $(echo $(lsof | grep "^python" | awk '{print $2} | sort -u ))`. Or simply use `pkill` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I need!

Comment: or:  for pid in $(lsof test11/ | awk $1 == "python" '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done @Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Combine `kill` with `lsof`:

```
 kill $(lsof -c python -ta +D /test11/)
```

A `kill` signal is sent to the terse output of `lsof`, (which is a list of `python` pids), active in the `/test11/` directory.